# Decoding JSON array

Tags: php, json

I'm struggling to parse a simple JSON array, am new to this so trying to learn.

Here's the data:

```
{"data":[
  {"name":"john","id":"123"},
  {"name":"dave","id":"345"}
  ], "other":
  {"foo":"bar"}
}
```

I only want the `data` information.

Here's what I'm trying (also what else I tried):

```
$list = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonURL),true);

foreach ($list as $element){

  //$id = $element->data->id; // this didn't work either
  //$name = $element->data->name; // this didn't work either

  $id = $element[data][id];
  $name = $element[data][name];

  $message .= $id.' - '.$name.'</br>';

}
```

Any ideas why it returns nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$json = '{"data":[
  {"name":"john","id":"123"},
    {"name":"dave","id":"345"}
      ], "other":
        {"foo":"bar"}
}';

$list = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ( $list['data'] as $item ) {
    echo $item['id'] . "\n";
    echo $item['name'] ."\n\n";
}
```

Here is a perfect example of how to work with that data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have errors in your code. Use strings to access members of the $element: `$element['data']`. Then, I would think that the entire data structure will be the first element of the list, so you can access it like this:

```
$list = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonURL),true);
$data = $list['data'];

$id = $data['id'];
$name = $data['name'];

$message .= $id.' - '.$name.'</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that everyone is telling you to access the data using arrays. JSON is a object based system, and you should access the data with the object notation. The problem was you were attempting to traverse the main object, not the `data` part of it.

You should do the following instead;

```
$list = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonURL),true);
$data = $list->data;

foreach ($data as $element) {
    $id = $element->id;
    $name = $element->name;

    $message .= $id.' - '.$name.'</br>';
}
```

Hope this helps.